# Connecting VisualVM to program running on OpenJDK 10 under windows 8.1 does not work

Tags: java, profile, visualvm, java-10

I am trying to profile my java application running on OpenJDK 10 using VisualVM 1.4.2 under windows 8.1 but when opening a connection to app in VisualVM, exception is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected composite type for ThreadInfo
    at sun.management.ThreadInfoCompositeData.validateCompositeData(ThreadInfoCompositeData.java:372)
    at sun.management.ThreadInfoCompositeData.getInstance(ThreadInfoCompositeData.java:68)
    at java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.<init>(ThreadInfo.java:263)
    at java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.from(ThreadInfo.java:794)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeBuilderViaFrom.fromCompositeData(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1018)
Caused: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Failed to invoke from(CompositeData)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.invalidObjectException(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1457)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeBuilderViaFrom.fromCompositeData(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1021)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeMapping.fromNonNullOpenValue(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:919)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$NonNullMXBeanMapping.fromOpenValue(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:133)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.fromOpenReturnValue(ConvertingMethod.java:131)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:168)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getThreadInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxSupport.isReadOnlyConnection(JmxSupport.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.isTakeThreadDumpSupported(JmxModelImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.resolveThreads(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.supportsViewFor(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.supportsViewFor(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:45)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceViewsManager.getViews(DataSourceViewsManager.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.openWindowAndAddView(DataSourceWindowManager.java:206)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.access$000(DataSourceWindowManager.java:50)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager$2.run(DataSourceWindowManager.java:117)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

the issue seems very similar to [Cannot open some applications in VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980120/cannot-open-some-applications-in-visualvm)  but the accepted workaround doesn't work for me. Any suggestions, please?

Previous lower java versions worked, btw.

EDIT: 
OracleJDK 11 does not work as well

Comment: Can you please post whole VisualVM log file not just the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting JDK bug [JDK-8165005](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165005). Please upgrade JDK 8 to JDK 8u152 or newer.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? My app is running on newer JDK.

Comment: or, do you mean JDK which runs visualVM?

Comment: Ok I've changed my default JVM (to 9) for executing VisualVM and it works now! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, VisualVM is running on old JDK 8. It will be visible in the log file.